# How to give predicted and label columns in BinaryClassificationMetrics evaluation for Naive Bayes model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a confusion regarding `BinaryClassificationMetrics` (Mllib) inputs. As per [Apache Spark 1.6.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#binary-classification), we need to pass **predictedandlabel** of Type `(RDD[(Double,Double)])` from transformed DataFrame that having predicted, probability(vector) & rawPrediction(vector).

I have created RDD[(Double,Double)] from Predicted and label columns. After performing `BinaryClassificationMetrics` evaluation on **NavieBayesModel**, I'm able to retrieve ROC, PR etc. But the values are limited, I can't able plot the curve using the value generated from this. Roc contains 4 values and PR contains 3 value.

Is it the right way of preparing **PredictedandLabel** or do I need to use **rawPrediction** column or **Probability** column instead of **Predicted** column?

Comment: You should try giving `BinaryClassificationMetrics` the raw probabilities and then set a number of bins when creating  `BinaryClassificationMetrics` to adjust the number of points. When using a model generated by spark (like a LogisticRegressionModel), you need to clear the threshold to get the whole spectrum of values.

Comment: @Hawknight . Edited the question with **rawPrediction** instead of **rawProbability**. I have a scenario which I need to use NavieBayesModel, clear threshold function is not available in this model. I hope you are specifying to the same column which I mention in this comment, not the **probability**

Comment: @Hawknight Is there any way to clear threshold explicitly from NavieBayesModel.

Comment: Which method did you use from `NaiveBayesModel` so far ?

Comment: I'm not using any method for clearing the threshold.

Comment: From my understanding, you should try to use the `predictProbabilities` method to get the desired output. Is that what you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

Prepare like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{NaiveBayes, NaiveBayesModel}

val df = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
val predictions = new NaiveBayes().fit(df).transform(df)

val preds = predictions.select("probability", "label").rdd.map(row => 
  (row.getAs[Vector](0)(0), row.getAs[Double](1)))
```

And evaluate:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics

new BinaryClassificationMetrics(preds, 10).roc
```

If predictions are only 0 or 1 number of buckets can be lower like in your case. Try more complex data like this:

```
val anotherPreds = df1.select(rand(), $"label").rdd.map(row => (row.getDouble(0), row.getDouble(1)))
new BinaryClassificationMetrics(anotherPreds, 10).roc
```